# Is it possible to get to a field annotation through a parameter without using its name as a String?

Tags: java, parameters, annotations, field

Is it possible to get to the `@Anno` instance of `var` from inside `printTitle`?

```
class MyClass {

  @Anno(title="Title") Integer var;

  void someFunc() {
    printTitle(var);
  }

  public void printTitle(Integer param) {
    // How to get to the @Anno annotation?
    // Is it possible to get to the 'Field' where param is coming from?
    Anno anno = param. ... .getAnnotation(Anno.class);
    if(annotation != null) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I do not want to use the name of `var` as a string `"var"` because that would be difficult to refactor later.

Comment: The answer to the question presented is: No. The way it's possible to do is given as the answer. If you don't want to use the name of the field as a `String`, don't write your code so it's dependent on field names. Process all the fields instead. Or change your whole design if it becomes evident that you were trying to do something "too clever".

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the annotation from a `String`, you need a `Field` object that represents `String var`.

```
  void someFunc() {
    printTitle("var");
  }

  public void printTitle(String field) {
    Anno anno = getClass().getField(field).getAnnotation(Anno.class);
    if(annotation != null) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but you use `field` as the reflection name, which is only checkable at run-time. I would rather have it checkable at compile-time. I will clarify that in my question.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you want, because you can't have it. It's my solution or nothing, you can't refer to `var` as the variable, you can only get the field by fetching `"var"` field from the class.

Comment: That's what I feared as well. I admit I was hoping for some magic/creative ideas. If it stays as it is your answer will be the accepted one.